# Update single common variable in parallel `foreach` loop

Tags: r

I need to run permutation analysis on neuroimaging data, which would normally be very demanding on memory if we store each permutation solution in memory. To avoid the problem, we keep track of how many times permutation results exceed the values of reference, thus all we need is a single vector of exceeding counts. This works fine in a `for` loop but I cannot figure out how to parallelize the task using `foreach`. My problem is that I cannot find a way to update a single common variable (or object) by individual `foreach` workers. All recommendations online are to create a data table with all the outputs of the foreach loop, but this is not efficient for big data analyses. I could try to have all `foreach` workers write to a common file, but then it would be another issue how to process such a file to get column-wise counts (not an elegant solution). Yet, the solution should be easy conceptually: every `foreach` worker should read and modify, thus reference, a single common vector kept in memory.

I use the ANTsR package for my analysis, which stores images as S4 objects (pointers to memory) to avoid duplications of information when passing arguments to functions, etc. Since S4 objects are pointers to memory, I though I can make `foreach` update a single S4 object, but looks like S4 pointers are not referenced properly when passed to `foreach` workers.

Anyone has a solution?

```
library(ANTsR)

# load example image and make a mask

img = antsImageRead(getANTsRData( "r16" ))
mask = getMask(img)


###########################################

library(doParallel) 
ncores = 2
registerDoParallel(cores=ncores) 

###############################

# parallel loop cannot update img S4 object

foreach (i=1:10, .combine='c', .export = c('img','mask'), 
         .packages = c('ITKR', 'ANTsRCore', 'ANTsR') ) %dopar% {

  # max(img) # output: 254
  # print(img@pointer) # output: <pointer: (nil)>
   img[mask] = 0 # output: no change to img
}

# standard for loop works

for (i in 1:10)  {
  # print(img@pointer) output: <pointer: 0x5510610>
  # max(img) # output: 254
   img[mask] = 0 # output: img black
}
```